# Group page returns empty array for feed using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I just created a Facebook closed group page and added one member (besides myself). I want to develop a website that when visited reads posts and comments and takes some action based on those. Only my login will be used to login to Facebook when visiting the website.

The index.php page code is

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([...]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes', 'user_posts', 'manage_pages'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://.../loggedin.php', $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

The loggedin.php code is:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([...]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
$req = '/'.PAGEID.'/feed';
$res = $fb->get($req);
$edge = $res->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
var_dump($edge);
```

The problem is that array of posts is empty.
If I change the $req to

```
$req = '/'.PAGEID.'/members'
```

I receive the right response.

If I change it to

```
$req = '/me/feed'
```

I received the right posts from my personal page.

What do I need to do get the posts from a closed group page that I have created?

Thanks

Comment: I create a test business page and I could get the posts on this new page using the same code. Is it even possible to get posts from a closed group? I am the admin of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the leading /.

```
$req = PAGEID.'/feed';
```

I still don't understand why **members** work with leading / but **feed** does not.